# How to set constructor parameter

Tags: powershell

How to instantiate with parameters?

Environment info:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion                                    

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
6      2      1
```

I have the following base class:

```
Class MyBaseClass {
[String]$SomeName
  MyBaseClass([String]$PrintThis) {
    Write-Host $PrintThis
  }
}
```

Instantiate:

```
function SomeFunction(){
    return [MyBaseClass("constructor parameter")]@{
      SomeName = "some name"
    }
}
```

If I remove the constructor it works with out the paremeter, but with a parameter in the constructor - then it says "Unexpected attribute" for the class name.

Error:

```
Unexpected attribute 'MyBaseClass.PowerShell
Attribute argument must be a constant or a script block.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete definition of the class (including any constructors you have defined), and the _exact_ error you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it

```
return New-Object MyBaseClass("") @{...}
```